# Doubly Linked List node's next is private

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm implementing a doubly linked list and I'm using an object of my own as the data being stored.

Here is my object:

```
#ifndef PLAY_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAY_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

class Play
{
private:
    int m_quarter;
    int m_minutes;
    std::string oTeam;
    std::string dTeam;
    int m_down;
    int m_yardToGO;
    int m_startLoc;
    int playDesc;
    std::string wholePlay;
    int relevance;
    int relCounter;
public:
    int getQuarter();
    int getMinutes();
    std::string getoTeam();
    std::string getdTeam();
    int getDown();
    int getYard();
    int getStartLoc();
    int getPlayDesc();
    std::string getwholePlay();
    Play(int quarter, int minutes, std::string offense, std::string defense, int dwn, int ytg, int start, int desc, std::string play, int relevance, int relCounter);
    ~Play();
    Play parse(std::string toParse);
    std::string findPlay(std::string playDesc);
};

#endif // PLAY_H_INCLUDED
```

-

Here is my node:

```
template<class T>
class node{
    friend class Play;
    T data;
    node *next, *prev;
    node(const T& t, node *n = 0, node *p = 0) {data=t; next=n; prev=p;}
};
```

The exact error I get is:

```
error: node<Play>* node<Play>::next is private.
```

I assume I get this problem because Play's information is private and inaccessible to node, and to fix this I tried making node a friend class of Play. When I did that I get errors saying "node is not a template type". The error makes no sense to me so I assume this isn't the way to correct my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: It was on line 10 of DLL.h, but declaring my node's data as public fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `public:` above properties which should be public. If you don't specify anything, everything  becomes private.

```
template<class T>
class node{
    public: // ADD THIS
    friend class Play;
    T data;
    node<T> *next, *prev;
    node(const T& t, node<T> *n = 0, node<T> *p = 0) { // EDIT

        data=t; next=n; prev=p;
    }
};
```

Edit: You always need use <> when using template classes, like I edited in above.

Answer (score 0):

All attributes in a class are private by default. Make it a `struct` instead or add `public:` at the beginning.

But I guess that is not the problem. When using `node *next, *prev;`, use this instead:

```
typedef typename node<T>* MyType;
MyType *next, *prev;
```